# How to fix chrome driver version issue in selenium and pyinstaller using python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I am trying top use google chrome driver to automate some functions so to run it I am using this line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

And it works correctly when I run but one I use Pyinstaller to convert the .py to .exe it gives me this error that points to the line above:

[image]

As I understood the main problem is because of the version of chrome driver, I am using the lateste version 100.+ but selenium supports only the version 92.+

Comment: I don't think the chrome driver version is an issue if, without packaging the script to exe, you can run the code with no error. Did you try downgrading the Pythinstaller version (3.6, etc)?

Comment: Thanks taht's solved my problem, can you put it as answer so we can help others please

Comment: Glad it worked! and I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is unlikely to be the Chrome Driver version. One way to check it is simply to run the full script and see if Chromedriver launched correctly or not.

In general, my approach to debugging the Pyinstaller error will be following.

1: Make sure Pyinstaller is not at the newest version (3.6 is my personal preference). I am not sure what is the issue with the newer Pyinstaller but it always gives me trouble when packaging executable.

2: If downgrading Pyinstaller not working, make sure the standalone script itself can run with no bug.

3: If the error persists, copy-paste the error msg to Google.

Comment: downgrading Pyinstaller was the best solution